# How to create text box in blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

I have started to make blackberry application. And facing a hard time. I want to create a log-in form, for that I need 2 text boxes, 2 labels (of user name and password) and one Submit Button.

Comment: Have you even got a look at the RIM Api ?http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this simple login field on screen.

```
Field loginField(){
        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
        vfm.add(new BasicEditField("UserName:", ""));
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
        vfm.add(new PasswordEditField("Password:", ""));
        vfm.add(new SeparatorField());
        vfm.add(new ButtonField("submit"));
        return vfm;
    }
```